# How to remove entered letters/strings or any inputs

Tags: c++, c, windows

I have made a hangman program in C. I have also started coding on C++.
My game asks for a word (string), then enter and the hangman screen appears. But because I entered the word before, we can cheat by pressing the UP arrow key and see the previous inputs. Is there any way to delete the previous input words from record? (on windows)
Please also tell me any specific terms if any for these types of things, Thank you;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SetConsoleHistoryInfo` with a history buffer size of 0 on Windows Vista / Server 2008 or later. Not sure about other platforms.

Comment: Well, on Unix type systems you need to link in readline libraries and use the readline functions to get command history and editing. The regular console input will not keep history.

Comment: Thanks but can you please explain how to implement this in code. I tried adding a line "bool SetConsoleHistoryInfo [0];" it compiles but no action and i used header file wincon.h

Comment: Oh just as you informed me! I was trying out on Windows XP, i will give it a try on my newer laptop with windows 7. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Another way (besides using `SetConsoleHistoryInfo`) is to implement an input of your program with getch() - there will be no history at all.

Example:

```
const int bufferSize = 2048;
wchar_t buffer[bufferSize];
memset( buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer) );
printf( "\nEnter string:\n" );

int charsEntered = 0;
while(1) {
    wchar_t ch = _getch();
    if( ch == L'\r' ) {
        break;
    } else if( ch == 8 ) {
        if( charsEntered == 0 ) {
            continue;
        }
        _putch( ch );
        _putch( L' ' );
        _putch( ch );
        charsEntered--;
    } else {
        buffer[charsEntered++] = ch;
        _putch( ch );
    }
}

wprintf( L"\nString: %s", buffer );
```

Comment: Yesm i know about getch() but the problem is you cant edit inputs with getch and recheck like rechecking before pressing enter

Comment: @ShoaibHaider I've added the example - this code allows to edit an input.